# What is an ISO file extension regarding a graphics file?

Tags: graphics

I've worked with ISO 9660 images files before, but now I'm working with Arbortext, a documents processing COTS software product for work with technical manuals.  It's taking a CGM file with redlining (editing with comments and a red circle around a part in a diagram) and saving it as an .iso file extension.

Does anyone know what type of iso file this is versus an ISO 9960 formatted file and is there a viewer outside of Arbortext for this graphics iso file type?

Comment: They're files for the IsoDraw technical drawing package.  Good question, just not about programming.

Comment: These graphics are being used under the S1000D technical spec, so I'm writing code for data modules that have the CGM (Computer Graphics Metafile) files in them.  Just not sure if this iso graphics file is a proprietary graphic or part of a standard.

Comment: [wotsit.org](http://www.wotsit.org/) is usually a good place to get answers to questions like this.  Sadly, it doesn't mention `.iso`, even for ISO 9660.

Comment: file extensions usually mean almost nothing - you'd probably want to try running the files past trid or file to see what they actually are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the information.  The file format: .iso is a custom or proprietary format for illustration files used by ArborText (PTC).  They take a CGM (Computer Graphics Metadata) file and convert it to an .iso file that can be viewed in one of their [products](http://www.ptc.com/WCMS/files/129373/en/6813_Creo_View_Chart4_TS_EN.pdf), including a free express version for non-illustrators.  See this [link](http://www.ptc.com/products/creo/view/express/).

It's not something I can easily view programmatically.  I did see where some people convert it to .eps (Encapsulated PostScript) for viewing.